# If this but not that, then if that but not this... Logic

Tags: jquery, logic

I'm trying to get a button (input field or button field) value each time a form is submitted.  I think I'm having some logic issues though because the second one does not work.

Here it is on jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/uqj88/23/

This is specifically the piece that's not working properly.  If it doesn't find input where type is submit, it doesn't even seem to look for a button element.

```
    $('form').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).children("input[type='submit']") != "") {
            submitButton = $(this).children("input[type='submit']");
            if (submitButton.attr("value") != ""){
                  linkText = submitButton.attr("value") + " - Button";
            }
            else if ((submitButton.attr("value") === "") && (submitButton.prop("id") != "")) {
                  linkText = submitButton.prop("id") + " - Button";
            }
            else if ((submitButton.attr("value") === "") && (submitButton.prop("class") != "")) {
                  linkText = submitButton.prop("class") + " - Button";
            }
            else {
                  linkText = "Form Submitted - Button";  
            }
        }
        else if ($(this).children("button") != "") {
            submitButton = $(this).children("button");
            linkText = submitButton.text() + " - Button";
        }
        window.alert(linkText);
    });
```

Comment: Oy; refactor, then figure it out.

Comment: `$(this).children("button")` will never be equal to `""`, it is always an object even if it doesn't find elements. The same is true for your first if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
$(this).children("input[type='submit']") != ""
```

should be:

```
$(this).children("input[type='submit']").length
```

jQuery  objects are always objects, regardless of whether or not they contain elements. An object will never be equal to `""`.

Repeat the same change for your else if statment.

Comment: Ahh I see.  If there is no element found, it just doesn't return anything?

Comment: It returns an empty jQuery object, but it is still an object. It just has a length property of 0 which is a falsy value in javascript.